# Run .bat as a Windows Service

Tags: batch-file, service, jar

I'm here again with another case that is getting me out my mind.

So, this is happening, I'm trying to run an executable java class(.jar) as a Windows Service, and all my attempts failed so far. To make it a little easier, I turned my jar into a batch file, wich only executes the jar in background, here is the code:

```
start "" javaw -jar C:\LocalService.jar
```

The batch works fine. However I have tried to install this batch as a service by using the next line in cmd:

```
sc create "LocalService" binPath= "C:\LocalService.bat"
```

The Service installs correctly, but as soon as I try to start it, it pops up an error (The code error is 1053, says something about the service did not start correctly)

Also, I have try with a software called NSSM (non-sucking service manager) It installs fine too, but the service does not start either.

Do you guys know what am I missing?

By the way, I'm doing all this on Windows 7 Professional.

Thanks!

Comment: Wrong tool according to me.  To wrap a jar in a Windows service use [Apache Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html).

Comment: Services are special libraries (sometimes programs) with specified functions that control starting and stopping. In Windows Resource Kit you'll find srvany which turns any program into a service (as far as possible). Either turn java program (java.exe?) or cmd.exe into a service running the jar or bat file. You might as well reduce complexity and run java direct.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comments
Both tools didnt work for me, sadly. However I was able to do it with a software called Java Service Wrapper. This is not a free software, so I needed to buy a license to get it to work.
The steps were simple:

1.-Create a folder with the name of the service, then inside add 4 folders: lib,bin,logs,conf

2.-On the lib folder you have to copy your jar and also the wrapper.jar and wrapper.dll (these last two are in the zip you download from the website)

3.-Copy 4 files to the bin folder: InstallApp-NT.bat.in, App.bat.in, UnintstallApp-NT.bat.in and wrapper.exe (this last one is the one that defines your license, if you can get a file wrapper.exe from somebody else who had paid a license it will work fine. These file also came in the zip from the website) Remove the .in from the batch files

4.-The most tricky step is this: You have to copy from the wrapper's folder called conf a file called wrapper.conf.in Remove the .in extension and edit it with a tex editor. The most important lines you have to edit are:

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java //Specify JRE Path. Will work with eviroment variable

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp //Choosing this class means your are using a .jar file to execute when the service starts

wrapper.java.classpath.1=C:\LocalService\lib\wrapper.jar //This one is constant. 
wrapper.java.classpath.2=C:\LocalService\lib\LocalService.jar //This is the path to your executable jar

wrapper.java.library.path.1=C:\LocalService\lib //Path to your own lib folder (the you created at the begining)

wrapper.app.parameter.1=C:\LocalService\lib\LocalService.jar // again the path to your jar
```

Then just execute the InstallApp-NT.bat and start the service and your are done

It worked to me with absolute paths, however according to documentation it will work fine with relative path too.
This is how I solved my problem and I hope someone with the same issue will find this helpful

See you next time!